# Visual Studio SOAP Service References Client: see XML message

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I've built SOAP based client using wsdl file and it works really good. One issue that I am having now is - I need to see original SOAP format messages (requests and responses) that are being sent and received.

It there any way how I can obtain XML requests/responses?

```
SomeClient Client = new SomeClient();
var response = Client.SomeMethod();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is for debugging purposes you could configure tracing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx. Or use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to capture HTTP traffic.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was seeking.

Comment: Isn't there a way through the logs to have the plaintext of it, without the 'hexdump' part of the data? without using Fiddler that is..

Comment: I answered my own question: "To omit hexadecimal data, specify protocolonly as the value for the tracemode attribute. The following example shows the trace when protocolonly is specified."
from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46fcs6sz.aspx to be clearer, the line to change is: <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024"> from includehex to protocolonly. Cheers